# jquery: Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        function back_to_top(){
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100);
        }
    });
</script>

<div class="toTop" onClick="back_to_top();">To up!</div>
```

When I click to this button, chrome show me this error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: back_to_top is not defined.**
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the jQuery DOM ready function creates a new scope, enclosing your function, which means it's not accessible from the global scope. Inline events must be in the global scope.

```
function back_to_top(){
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100);
}
$(function () {

});
```

Or drop the inline handler and use unobtrusive JavaScript.

```
$(function () {
    function back_to_top(){
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100);
    }

    $('.toTop').click(function(){
        back_to_top();
    });
});
```

HTML with no inline handler:

```
<div class="toTop">To up!</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put back_to_top outside the jquery document ready function

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has function scope. That means that variables (including function declarations) defined within a function, will only be available in that function.
i.e. in this case `back_to_top` is only accessible within the `$(function(){...})`.

`...onClick="back_to_top();"` is looking at the global scope and `back_to_top` is not available. You can expose it though if you do something like this:

```
$(function () {
        window.back_to_top = function {
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100);
        }
    });
```

I don't think this is ideal but it will work in your case. A better way is to attach a listener. Have a look at jQuery [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method.

Hope it helps.